# AjaxControlToolkit FileUpload not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

in my aspx:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxFileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete"     AllowedFileTypes="xlsx" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

in my aspx.cs:

```
protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
    // Handle the uploaded file here
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Templates/Upload/" + e.FileName);
    ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
```

i am having an issue that on upload the file, it does not break into the `UploadComplete` function in my aspx.cs

Comment: I have just looked at a (very much) older implementation I have of this and my code is near enough identical. The only major difference is that I am hooking into the OnClientUploadComplete event, too. Albeit only to show the status to the UI, but maybe it requires this? I would recommend finding a newer file upload control anyway as this one is extremely dated.

Comment: @Ripmax do you have any other suggested ways to upload .xlsx file to server?

Comment: That ajax upload control is still maintained by the folks from DevExpress, and they are a high quality  maker of .net software tools and add-ins. They have maintained the aj toolkit and this control for many years now, and have updated the aj toolkit over time. The control is fantastic, free, open source, allows un-limited file size (is chunked), and you be hard pressed to find a better and more able up-loading tool set then this one. I high recommended using this up-loading control. See my post below.  You don't mention or note how you installed the aj toolkit (I suggest nuget).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it not clear how you installed the toolkit (NuGet, or a zip download).

A simple drag + drop of the ajaxfileupload control should wire up the page correctly.

However, you also need a script manager on the page (and you need that script manager for just about any control from the toolkit).

So, the process with an empty page looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the above automatic adds the assembly reference to the page.

And as noted, the page did have a script manager dropped into the page (drop in the script manager right after the form tag).

So, our page markup now looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpLoadTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web35.UpLoadTest" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div style="padding:35px;width:40%">


            <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
            
                />

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point, we could (should) try using the property sheet to add the upload file event.

So, select the control, and now display the property sheet.

So, then this:

[image]

So, in most cases, let vs write and create the event stub for you.

The above created this event stub, and let's add some code to save the file.

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        // One file uploaded, save it

        string sFileAndPath = Server.MapPath($@"~\UpLoadFiles\{e.FileName}");

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(sFileAndPath);

    }
```

However, before ANY of the above?

We have to add to the web.config in the config section, add this:

```
<system.webServer>

<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

(you probably have a handler’s section in web.config, so use that).

As you can see, this is why I again suggest you use NuGet to install the toolkit.

The above should result in the control now working for you.

The end result is a really nice upload control. It allows un-limited size and has a drag + drop hot spot. So, say this:

[image]